# Чем определяется прочтение сочетания букв ИЕ (ИЙЭ или ИЭ)?

Tags: орфоэпия, корень-слова, йот

Приведу примеры таких слов:

> *пиетет, риелтор, диета, риет* (блюдо, похожее на паштет), *гиена, Сиена* (город в Италии), *сиеста, фиеста.*

Я, конечно, имею в виду корневые сочетания, а не слова типа *"приедет", "качающиеся", "настроение"* или *"гниение".* Со словом *"триединство"* на стыке корней также не возникает вопросов.

Естественно, можно проверить каждое слово в отдельности и узнать, что слово *"риет",* например, из французского (*rillette*) и поэтому читается с йотом, а слово *"пиетет"* знать, что произносится через Э, будучи просто образованным человеком. *Но что делать, если видишь перед собой новое или просто малоупотребимое слово с этим сочетанием (которое не слышал из авторитетного источника)? Как его произносить? Есть на этот счёт какие-нибудь правила?*

Из перечисленных хотелось бы узнать, как правильно прозносить слова *"сиеста"* и *"Сиена".*

И вообще, хотелось бы понять, много ли таких слов всего, оценить порядок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос серьёзный, меня он тоже интересует уже давно, но вряд ли мы сейчас найдём точные рекомендации по произношению буквы Э. Видимо, эта буква русскому языку всё ещё чужда, за 2 века так и не освоена, до сих пор и с написанием, и с произношением трудности, последовательности в употреблении этой буквы не наблюдается.

В научной литературе чаще обсуждается графическая проблема - написание е/э.
в качестве лингвистических оснований для написания выделяются а) этимологические основания, б) фонетические основания (произношение).

Э т и м о л о г и ч е с к о г о подхода в отвлечении от других свойств слова придерживался Я.К. Грот, продемонстрировавший это на двух примерах: «Неправильно пишется э в слове “проэкт”: так как и в латинском языке, откуда оно взято, е следует за j, т.е. является йотованным, то надо писать проект. То же замечание относится к слову реестр, которое в этом виде ближе к своему латинскому первообразу (registrum), чем будучи написано “реэстр”» [Грот 1888: 77]. В этих случаях для Грота, судя по всему, существенным является этимологическое написание слова (так как произношение для латинского языка, который является мертвым, установить невозможно); в отношении слова реестр основанием для отказа от буквы «э» является прикрытость второго слога этимона.

В плане ф о н е т и ч е с к и х оснований графическая оппозиция «э/е»
после гласных связана с определением йотированного / нейотированного произношения у слов в данной позиции. Это представляет определенную проблему.

Среди слов с [э] в поствокальном положении выделяется группа слов с предшествующим [и] – в связи с тем что, по свидетельству А.Б. Шапиро,

> «в русском языке между и и э обычно развивается звук “йот”, почему,
>   по мере распространения слов с сочетанием иэ в русской речи, более
>   соответствующим их произношению является написание ие» [Шапиро 1951:
>   49]. Это свойство нашло отражение в правилах правописания.

Другие исследователи, однако, отмечают, что

> «“йот” развивается не во всех заимствованных словах. Орфоэпические
>   словари в качестве нормы в целом ряде слов рекомендуют произношение
>   [иэ]» [Максимова 1965: 83–84]. Примеры цитируемого автора: Диего,
>   миелит, пиетет, тамплиер. Ср. данные «Орфоэпического словаря русского
>   языка» под ред. Р.И. Аванесова 1989 года издания: помета
>   нейотированного произношения [иэ] дается, например, при словах диез,
>   диета, сиеста, спаниель, реквием, триер. В «Словаре трудностей
>   русского произношения» [Каленчук, Касаткина 2001] дано вариативное
>   произношение для слов диез и диета.

Л.К. Максимовой в работе 1964 года констатируется зависимость произношения интервокального йота от его места по отношению к ударению:

> «В слабой позиции для j перед безударным [э] звук [j] как правило не
>   произносится. Наличие или отсутствие j можно определить только в том
>   случае, если j находится в сильной позиции, т.е. перед [э] под
>   ударением, например: по[э]т, гиги[jэ]на» [Максимова 1964: 35].
>   Отмечается также следующее: «Реализации фонемы [j] в позиции между
>   гласными [иjэ] в русском литературном языке связаны с конкретными
>   словами. Например: [j] произносится в словах сердцебиение, гиена,
>   избиение, клиент; вариативно произношение – градиент, диета, тамплиер;
>   а в словах – риелтор, спаниель, пациент, коэффициент [j] не
>   произносится» [Арзиани 2004: 7].

http://nauka.x-pdf.ru/17raznoe/304546-3-aktualnie-problemi-orfografii-inoyazichnih-zaimstvovaniy-moskva-udk-8137345-bbk-812rus-8-n59-nechaeva-aktualnie-p.php

Итак, в заимствованных словах часто после гласных буква «е» обозначает звук[э] : риелтор, сиеста, проект. Такое произношение многим кажется «не по-русски», но это норма, зафиксированная словарями.

С другой стороны, сколько всего на практике в живой речи  встречается слов (как нарицательных имён, так и собственных), в которых буквосочетание "ИЕ" произносится нейотированно? ***Пациент, коэффициент, спаниель, риелтор***. Все остальные слова (диез, диета и пр.), **несмотря на частые рекомендации произносить их без [j], на практике всё равно произносят с йотом**, в соответствии с русским произношением.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Наконец-то кто-то ответил!) Как будет время, обязательно прочитаю.

Comment: Прочитал, очень интересно! Никогда не слышал, чтобы "диету" и "диез" без йота произносили. Задумался я как сам "градиент" произношу, наверно, всё-таки нейотированно.